# Train track design

Tags: trains, tracks

I have some old lego train tracks from **1984 set: 7715** and I would like to use them with
my latest **Lego train set: 60197** to increase the size of my layout, are these tracks compatible?
or can they be adapted? I only want to run the 60197 train but would like to use up the old track.